# Add data folder recursively using data_files in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, installation, data-files, sdist

I want to add folders `mydata1` and `mydata2` in root package recursively when install my project. So I write this function in `setup.py`:

```
def gen_data_files(*dirs):
    results=[]
    for datadir in dirs:
        results.extend([(p, [os.path.join(p,f) for f in files]) for p, subdirs, files in os.walk(datadir)])
    return results
```

And then in `setup.py`:

```
setup(
    #...
    data_files=gen_data_files('mydata2', 'mydata2'),
    #...
)
```

Creating the sdist is ok: `setup.py sdist upload -r mypypi`

But when I install, an exception was throw: `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`.

I'm new in Python. So I don't know why. Can you help me in this case? Thanks!

**EDIT:**
Those codes have the same `results`:

```
results.extend([(p, [os.path.join(p,f) for f in files]) for p, subdirs, files in os.walk(datadir)])

results.extend((p, [os.path.join(p,f) for f in files]) for p, subdirs, files in os.walk(datadir))
```

Answer (score 0):

The function should be:

```
def gen_data_files(*dirs):
    results = []
    for datadir in dirs:
        for p, subdirs, files in os.walk(datadir):
            results.extend((p, os.path.join(p, f)) for f in files)
    return results
```

Also, may I suggest using [setuptools](http://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html).

Comment: I searched google many times for this and maybe I tried somethings like your link about setuptools. The tutorial in your link is quite long. Maybe I missed something so I cannot resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry everybody, the issue is my version `5.99999`. Too long. Use somethings like `6.0` fixed.